# Can I trust opera browser free VPN?

Tags: privacy, vpn, trust

When  traffic leaves the VPN, the operator of the VPN server can see the websites I'm accessing. Opera browser has a `free VPN`. Can I trust this VPN?

https://www.opera.com/features/free-vpn

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to say if a VPN provider and infrastructure is actually trustable for an unknown purpose (the only information about the purpose were "can I trust"). It is even impossible to evaluate the specific VPN if your purpose was actually more clear. Apart from developing a threat model for your purpose a proper evaluation would then likely involve checking the code involved at the client and server side against accidental bugs and deliberate backdoors, checking the infrastructure and how well it is protected against unauthorized access, and and and ...

In other words: No, it is not **fully** trustable. Nothing is. It might still be trustable enough to reduce risks which you have when using an open hotspot. But you are still relying on a third party for code and infrastructure. Running your own VPN instead is likely more trustable, but even in this case you usually rely on code which you don't fully understand and control and run your VPN endpoint in an infrastructure you don't fully control either.

Answer (score 1):

Placing your trust in any individual third party is inherently bad. The VPN provider (in this case Opera) will have all your traffic, and there is no way to know what they do with it. So the question of trust becomes "Do you trust this third party that they won't misuse your data, taking into account that there is probably no way for you to find out if they did?".

If you want to stay anonymous, use mixnets like the [Tor project](https://www.torproject.org/).